# Aggregate rows with condition in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

## The Problem

Having a web application where users can solve exams consisting of different types of questions (multiple choice, single choice), I need to select the percentage score for a user submission. I am using **PostgreSQL 13.x**

## Schema

```
exams (id)
questions (id)
answers (id, question_id, correct)
exam_questions (exam_id, question_id)
exam_answers (user_id, exam_id, answer_id)
```

## What I have

I managed to come up with a query, which selects the data I need:

```sql
SELECT a.id, a.question_id, a.correct, (CASE WHEN ea.answer_id::bool THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END) as selected
     FROM answers a
     FULL OUTER JOIN exam_answers ea
         ON a.id = ea.answer_id AND ea.exam_id = ?
     WHERE a.question_id IN (
         SELECT eq.question_id
         FROM exam_questions eq
         WHERE eq.exam_id = ?
     );
```

Which returns something like:

```
|id|question_id|correct|selected|
|--|-----------|-------|--------|
|1 |1          |true   |false   |
|2 |1          |false  |true    |
|3 |1          |false  |false   |
|4 |1          |false  |false   |
|5 |2          |true   |false   |
|6 |2          |true   |true    |
|7 |2          |false  |false   |
|8 |2          |false  |true    |
```

If possible, how can I modify this SQL to find how many questions have their correct answers completely intersect with the selected ones to get the score?

Comment: (1) `full join` should not be needed assuming the data has proper foreign key references.  (2) desired results would make the question clearer.

Comment: The FULL JOIN doesn't return FULL JOIN result anyway, thanks to the WHERE clause condition.

Comment: There might not be an entry for every answer, that’s why I used a FULL JOIN. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following example:

```
WITH answers_sheet AS (
  -- < your query > --
)
SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS total_questions,
  SUM((correct = correct_selected) :: int) AS total_correct
FROM (  
  SELECT question_id,
    SUM(correct :: int) AS correct,
    SUM((correct AND selected) :: int) AS correct_selected
  FROM answers_sheet
  GROUP BY question_id
) agg
```

From your resulting dataset, it will get:

```
total_questions     total_correct
2                   0
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=061175a3364268bea912edbdedaf3f01)

In your SQL query it is enough to use the `LEFT JOIN` instead of the `FULL OUTER JOIN`. And there is no selection by user.

```
SELECT a.id, a.question_id, a.correct, 
       (CASE WHEN ea.answer_id::bool THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END) as selected
FROM exam_questions eq
JOIN answers a ON a.question_id = eq.question_id
LEFT JOIN exam_answers ea 
       ON a.id = ea.answer_id 
      AND ea.user_id = ? -- ???
WHERE eq.exam_id = ?
```